# Buffer Size Issue with Npcap in Windows 10 using pcap.h in C++

Tags: c++, pcap, winpcap, npcap

I have encountered an issue while trying to set a large buffer size using Npcap in a C++ program on Windows 10. The code works correctly when using WinPcap, obtaining the desired 2GB buffer size, but fails to achieve the same result with Npcap. I am seeking guidance on resolving this issue.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcap.h>

void packet_handler(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr, const u_char *packet) {
    // Your packet handling logic goes here
    // This function will be called for each captured packet
    std::cout << "Packet captured!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    // Change "eth0" to your network interface name
    const char *dev = "eth0";

    // Open the capture interface
    pcap_t *handle = pcap_open_live(dev, 65536, 1, 1000, errbuf);

    if (handle == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open device " << dev << ": " << errbuf << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set the buffer size
    int buffer_size = 2147483647; // 2 GB
    if (pcap_set_buffer_size(handle, buffer_size) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set buffer size: " << pcap_geterr(handle) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Start capturing packets
    if (pcap_loop(handle, 0, packet_handler, nullptr) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error during packet capture: " << pcap_geterr(handle) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Close the capture handle
    pcap_close(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that `pcap_set_buffer_size` didn't Get 2GB RAM while I used Npcap!

The provided code works correctly on Windows with WinPcap, achieving the desired 2GB buffer size. However, when using Npcap, the same code fails to obtain the expected buffer size from RAM.

Comment: How do you know that it's not working? Does it return an error?

Comment: What's the size instead of G RAM? Or what happens?

Comment: @AlanBirtles From Task Manager! I see in Npcap RAM didn't Increase.

Comment: @LajosArpad This is just an example, `pcap_set_buffer_size`  didn't work correctly in NPcap while it works Correctly in WinPcap.I require a buffer size of 2 gigabytes.

Comment: Define "didn't work correctly"

Comment: @LajosArpad I require a buffer size of 2 gigabytes `pcap_set_buffer_size` set the buffer size for a not-yet-activated capture handle. which means I should see My RAM will increase by 2 gigabytes as I Run that code!
for example, if the current state of RAM is 4 it should be 6 and as I stop my program it should be 4 again! This means `pcap_set_buffer_size ` did its job correctly.

Comment: I'd guess npcap is simply using a more efficient way of reserving memory so that's it's not using memory until it's written to. Have you tried using it and found it's not able to use 2gb of ram?

Comment: FYI: [Npcap buffer sizes are not well-documented](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/issues/30)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah,  I conducted a test on it, evaluating its performance at a scale of 10 GB of data.  it didn't increase the pcap Buffer size and I had packets lost :)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for the Link you sent But I didn't understand how can I fix my issue.

Comment: Hey, your issue might be completely unrelated to the RAM "issue" you think you are seeing.  There is a good chance that it doesn't actually take up any physical RAM space until that space is *written* to.  And even then, it will only take up 4K at a time.  This is how modern operating systems work.

Comment: @Jason But how does that function take 2GB RAM as I use WinPcap? My code and OS are the same I only change Winpcap and npcap for testing. I don't know which things were changed in NPcap vs WinPcap related to the `pcap_set_buffer_size` function.

Comment: They are different libraries that can allocate memory differently.  Just because the task manager isn't reporting the memory you expect, doesn't mean it isn't allocated to your process.  Memory management in modern systems is *a lot* more complex than that.

Comment: @Jason How Can I check that? could you explain how dose NPcap do that? Because as I test with WinPcap I do not have any lost But By NPcap I have! How could you be sure that NPcap takes that 2GB?

Comment: What I'm explaining has literally nothing to do with those libraries and everything to do with memory management in modern systems.  I just made a program that calls `malloc` for 33GB of memory (My system has 32 total), then writes to a couple random places in the buffer.   It not only worked, but the task manager currently says it's only using `.3MB`.

Comment: @Jason Well, How Can I fix that code to Get that Buffer Size? I don't know what should I do. The Point is that 2GB was not for my program process! its for pcap!

Comment: ... What I'm telling you is that you *are* getting that buffer size.  When you allocate memory, it doesn't reserve all of that memory in physical RAM, it allocates virtual addresses.  If my 33G `malloc` actually went out to RAM, it would have brought my system to its knees.

Comment: @Jason So why as I change library to WinPcap it takes? The process of My program was not take 2GB, Pcap will Take that buffer size and I see RAM will increase by 2GB.

Comment: It's probably unwise for me to explain modern system architecture in the comments of this question.  These are implementation details that you are asking about.  [Here](https://github.com/wireshark/winpcap) is the source for winpcap and [here](https://github.com/nmap/npcap) is the source for npcap.  Some things you can search for on the internet that might help you: "virtual memory", "what is a pointer", "why malloc never fails", "what is a page fault"

Comment: @Jason What you describe sounds like something which I know is used in Linux where [over-committing](https://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html) is supported. I.e. the `malloc()` returns immediately a (virtual) address but memory isn't really allocated until an address (or actually the page it belongs to) is accessed. Though, I'm not aware that this technique is used on Windows as well. ([Will Microsoft Windows 10 overcommit memory?](https://superuser.com/a/1228040/1130896))

Comment: @Scheff'sCat  You are correct, I'm primarily a Linux guy, but I did compile and run this code on Windows 10.  According to your link the limit is RAM size + page file size, which my code stays within.  Though, aside from that limit, it does appear to behave in a similar  way.